# Send data to a chrome packaged app javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app, data-stream

I'm currently facing an issue, and I hope some of you may have an answer to this.

I have a chrome webapp and a Rails 4 application, and users can currently download files from my website. Basically, what I would like to achieve is to be able to redirect (I don't know if this is the right word for this, send might be better) the downloaded file to my webapp, so it can handle it.

What would be great would be a solution like streaming a buffer to my app, or something like this, but I really don't know if such a thing exists, and my researches on the Web didn't find much...

Does any of you think about a solution?

EDIT: Explanations about what I'm trying to do:

I want to be able to use what I've downloaded directly in my webapp. The idea of what I'm developping is to create a webplatform where I can download applications and then put in on a electronic device (Arduino-like). The Chrome application would be to make the download and putting on the board process automatic so users don't have to lose time by doing every single step.

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to achieve better. So far it's hard to understand.

Comment: Well, I want to be able to use what I've downloaded directly in my webapp. The idea of what I'm developping is to create a webplatform where I can download applications and then put in on a electronic device (Arduino-like). The Chrome application would be to make the download and putting on the board process automatic so users don't have to lose time by doing every single step. EDIT: I'll put that on my post aswell.

Comment: To summarize: you want files that are downloaded through a normal Chrome tab to be handled by your app?

Comment: Not exactly. This may be a solution to my issue, but I also wanted to know if it was possible to get files directly from the location where they are downloaded in the "regular" way (I mean in a chrome tab), without going through this process.

Comment: Maybe [URL handlers](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/url_handlers) or [File handlers](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/file_handlers) will do the trick. I still don't fully understand your question.

Comment: The term "webapp" is not precise enough. Can you clarify whether this is a Chrome App or a web page that's just running some JavaScript locally? If it's a Chrome App, there are both restrictions that don't apply to web pages and additional APIs that web pages can't access. (If it is not a Chrome App, please remove the google-chrome-app tag.)

Comment: This is a Chrome App, using some of the Chrome libraries and such.

Comment: Please edit your question to refer to "Chrome App" and not "webapp." They're very different things. It's especially confusing given that you're specifically mentioning Rails 4 in your question, which would be irrelevant if this is a Chrome App question (because a Chrome App speaking to a web service wouldn't care which framework you used to build the web service... that is, unless you really mean webapp, in which case we might care that it's Rails 4). BTW, you probably want to remove the ruby-on-rails tag as well, because the Rails question monitors are going to say WTF.